How to fix React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'fetchData'
I am currently using useEffect and I get this error below

"WARNING in src\newComponents\jobSearch\UseFetch.js   Line 36:8:
React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'fetchData'. Either
include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
"

Here is my function


  const fetchData = async () => {
        setIsLoading(true);
        try {
            const response = await axios.request(options);

            setData(response.data.data);
            setIsLoading(false);
        } catch (error) {
            setError(error);
            console.log(error)
        } finally {
            setIsLoading(false);
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData();
    }, []);



Can you please help me out

Did you import the useEffect

@UdanJayanith yes I did

Try removing [ ] in useEffect or pass a value to useEffect dependency list

If you want to define the async function outside of the useEffect hook, you have to add it to the dependency list of useEffect and wrap its definition into a useCallback with the necessary dependencies to prevent unnecessary calls.

i'm confused as to what is happening here.  i'm currently staring at some working code i wrote that has a useEffect with an empty dependency array that calls an async function defined a few lines above it.  looks remarkably similar to this, but i'm not getting this warning.  what exactly is causing the warning?

Use a IIFE: useEffect(() => {
void (async fetchData() { ... })()
}, [])

(1) That is just a warning, not an error, (2) your code is likely correct if you only want to fetch data once when the component mounts, so either move fetchData into the useEffect body (to remove it as an external dependency) or add a comment to disable the linter rule for the dependency array.
